# Set active class in a Php foeach

Tags: php

I have the following code to display a list of taxonomies in Wordpress. It works and my only concern is the active class (li class="active"). Err, how do I go about making it dynamic?

```
        <ul id="filter">    
        <?php       
        echo '<li class="active"><a href="#" class="all">All</a></li>'; # this remains static and unchanged             
            if ( $count > 0 ) {             
                foreach ( $mylinks as $mylink ) {
                    echo '<li>';
                    # get current webdirectory and link to taxonomy menus
                    echo'<a href=' . network_site_url() . '/services/' .$mylink->slug . ' class='. $mylink->slug .'" >';
                    echo $mylink->name;
                    echo "</a>";
                    echo "</li>";
                }
            }   
        ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no idea what is `$link->slug` is it a post type property? or taxonomy? Something else? in case of something else you can use a [strpos](http://php.net/stripos) in comparing url?

```
echo'<a href=' . network_site_url() . '/services/' .$mylink->slug . ' class='. ($mylink->slug) 
    . (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $mylink->slug) !== false ? ' active ':'').'" >';
```

in case  of post use [get_post_field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field)

```
global $wp_query; // little trick...
echo'<a href=' . network_site_url() . '/services/' .$mylink->slug . ' class='. ($mylink->slug) 
    .($mylink->slug === get_post_field('slug', get_the_ID(), false) ? ' active ':'').'" >';
```

in case of this is a taxonomy archive page using a query object (actualy you can use it in axample above too)...

```
global $wp_query; // little trick...
echo'<a href=' . network_site_url() . '/services/' .$mylink->slug 
    . ' class='. ($mylink->slug) .($mylink->slug === $wp_query->queried_object->slug ? ' active ':'').'" >';
```